# What's the easiest way to convert an Int32's bytes to String?

Tags: .net, string, integer, hex

```
Dim intChunkId As Integer = &H4D546864   
Dim strChunkId As String = "MThd"

Dim easiestWay = GetString(intChunkId)
```

`easiestWay` should now equal `strChunkId`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim bytes As Byte() = BitConverter.GetBytes(intChunkId)
Dim strChunkId As String = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes)
```

A couple of points:

1. This assumes the bytes in the integer are all the ASCII range (the ones in your example are, but they might not always be: in that case, you can use `Encoding.Default`.)
2. My VB is a bit rusty, I'm not sure I got the declaration of arrays right...

Comment: im talking about .net, vb & cs are just the same.
so u say there is no a magic ASCII.GetString overload for integer... urgh.

Comment: @Shimmy: yeah, but it's only one extra line :-)

Comment: It's one extra processing.
I guess I will make a second static readonly variable that contains the calculated result.